# Exploring the Converse of the Stolz-Cesàro Theorem: sufficient Conditions and Existence.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

> **Stolz-Cesàro theorem case $\frac{*}{\infty}$:-**
> If $b_n $ is a monotone increasing sequence and $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} b_n = \infty $,
> and if $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}- b_n}= l \in \overline{\mathbb{R}} $, then  $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n }{b_n}=l$.

> **Stolz-Cesàro theorem case $\frac{0}{0}$:-**
> If $b_n $ is a monotone decreasing sequence and $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} b_n = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}  a_n = 0 $,
> and if $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}- b_n}= l \in \overline{\mathbb{R}} $, then  $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n }{b_n}=l$.

I saw this interesting question: Calculate
$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left( \sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!} - \sqrt[n]{n!}\right) $$
The first thing that I noticed is that this sequence is the converse of Stolz-Cesàro theorem for the famous limit $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n} = \frac{1}{e}$, which in fact, is the correct limit for $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left( \sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!} - \sqrt[n]{n!}\right) $.

This got me wondering: Is the converse of the Stolz-Cesàro theorem correct? In other words:

> **Converse of Stolz-Cesàro theorem case $\frac{*}{\infty}$:-**
> If $b_n $ is a monotone increasing sequence and $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} b_n = \infty $,
> and if  $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n }{b_n}=l \in \overline{\mathbb{R}} $, then  $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}- b_n}= l$.

> **Converse of Stolz-Cesàro theorem case $\frac{0}{0}$:-**
> If $b_n $ is a monotone decreasing sequence and $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} b_n = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}  a_n=0$,
> and if  $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n }{b_n}=l \in \overline{\mathbb{R}} $, then  $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}- b_n}= l$.

The answer is no! For example let $a_n = (-1)^n, \ b_n =n. $ Then $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} =0$, but $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}- b_n}$ doesn't even exist.

$\color{red}{\textbf{I want to ask:}}$ What are the sufficient conditions for $b_n , a_n$ such that we have a converse to the Stolz-Cesàro theorem? Is there a converse to the Stolz-Cesàro theorem somewhere, or has nobody tried to come up with one?

---

**Why do I think there might be a converse ?** The limit $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left( \sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!} - \sqrt[n]{n!}\right) $ gave me the idea that some sequences have a converse to  Stolz-Cesàro theorem, and I remembered that there was a converse for Cauchy limit theorem  (which, in fact, is a weaker version of the Stolz-Cesàro theorem in Real numbers ).

> **Cauchy limit theorem:-** If $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = a \in \overline{\mathbb{R}} $, then $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum \limits_{k=1}^ n a_k}{n} = a$.

Converse of Cauchy limit theorem:- If $|n(a_n - a_{n-1})|\leq M \in \mathbb{R} \forall n $, and if $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum \limits_{k=1}^ n a_k}{n} = a$, then $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = a $.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448624/converse-of-stolz-cesaro

Comment: There might be other different sufficient conditions if you look up converses to Abelian or Tauberian theorems. Also, I think you meant "sufficient" conditions, not necessary.

Comment: @dezdichado there is no answers to this question and it doesn't have the converse of $\frac{0}{0}$ case

Comment: @dezdichado :  'I think you meant "sufficient" conditions, not necessary' I am bad at English ,thank you for pointing that out for my

Comment: @dezdichado I never heard about these theorems where did you read about them? can you recommend me a book that include them ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't use Stolz - Cesaro theorem because the condition that the limit exists can't be proven](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4810918/cant-use-stolz-cesaro-theorem-because-the-condition-that-the-limit-exists-can)